# Using R to get the median of every 1000 rows

Tags: r, median, data-wrangling, binning

I have a very large dataset (thousands of rows) that starts as follows:

| Position | Counts |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |

I want to 'bin' (not sure if it's the right word choice) the rows in 1000 and get the median of the Counts for each of these 1000 rows. In a sense the Position column values are not important as I just want every 1000 rows.

I plan to eventually plot the coverage of the counts in a histogram to see the trend.

Comment: So every 1000 rows we want one median? if we have 2000 rows then expected output is 2 rows? Or do we want rolling median, 2000 rows input, 2000 rows output?

Comment: The former. One median for every 1000 rows.

Comment: Great, then you will find answers in the linked post.

Answer (score 1):

here is a `data.table` approach

based on your sample data, I calculated the means of chunks of 3 rows. replace the 3 with the number 1000 in your production code, assuming that `Position` is unique and increments by 1 each row. If not, you have to create a unique, incremental rowid first.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("Position   Counts
0   0
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   2
5   2")

# create group id's (3 rows per group, replace with 1000 in production code)
DT[, .(median= median(Counts)), by = .(chunk = Position %/% 3)]

#    chunk median
# 1:     0      1
# 2:     1      2
```